# Light field plugin - array of renderings?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I am new to blender and light fields and I used the Blender plugin to create a base grid over my image, a rig and a camera and light source, but I would like to render multiple views of my initial image (like in http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/HCI/Research/LightField/images/lumigraphVisualization.png). It might be an easy question, but my lack of experience with Blender doesn't help me much. Also, I am using now a normal static image. Should I be using a 3D mash? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes you need 3D data for light-field to work.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5034/what-is-lightfield-tools-plugin-for